# Not float when reading from file. C program

Tags: c

I'm stuck with my program here where it reads the data from a text file but it did not obtain the float part as float. 
Instead of 43.23, it prints 43.00 after it reads from my .txt file. 
Where did I do wrong?

```
    dir[k].age=atol(strtok(NULL,","));
    dir[k].weight=atol(strtok(NULL,","));
    dir[k].height=atol(strtok(NULL,"\n"));
```

Comment: You already identified the _reading_ part of your code as source of unwanted behaviour. Hence roughly 90% of the code provided in your question is useless noise. Users on stackoverflow are much more likely to provide good answers if the question is concise.

Comment: Now you've deleted a bit too much, but you're on the right way ;-) it is essential to know that `weight`and `height`  are `float`s. you should remove `dir[k]` too, since the reader does not know what it is at the moment (and the use of an array of structs is not relevant to the question). P.S.: I'm not writing this to annoy you, but to help you ask even better questions in the future.

Comment: Thank you. Appreciate your help. Wanted to fix the question but I forgot what I was doing at this point in time.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
dir[k].weight=atol(strtok(NULL,","));
dir[k].height=atol(strtok(NULL,"\n"));
```

[atol](http://linux.die.net/man/3/atol) reads a `long`. You probably wanted [atof](http://linux.die.net/man/3/atof).

Answer (score 3):

```
dir[k].weight=atol(strtok(NULL,","));
dir[k].height=atol(strtok(NULL,"\n"));
```

You are using a function that converts to integers, so that doesn't know how to handle fractional parts. Use `strtof` instead, that even allows for error checking, in contrast to the `ato*` functions.

Answer (score 1):

Here:

```
dir[k].weight=atol(strtok(NULL,","));
dir[k].height=atol(strtok(NULL,"\n"));
```

You are reading values as long